# font color doesn't work

Tags: html, ios

I have the following html segment presented in my iPad app.

```
<font size="4px" face="HelveticaNeue" color=rgb(49,49,49)>ABC</font>
```

It is supposed be dark grey, and it does below iOS 5.1. But on iOS 6 it is in green, and it shows  green color in chrome and firefox as well.

Is there any mistake in above code? Why does it work in previous iOS?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding quotes? `color="rgb(49,49,49)"` And use styles instead of the font tag.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Adding quotes doesn't work. I have fixed the issue by using style. It is legacy code. I just wonder the reason of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT), the value of the `size` attribute in a `font` element has a numeric value, without any unit, and the value is taken as an index to a browser-dependent array of sizes. Besides, `4px` would make little size if taken as in CSS to mean 4 pixels – at that size, almost all fonts become illegible. Spaces are significant in font names, so `HelveticaNeue` is quite different from `Helvetica Neue`. And the `color` attribute value must be either a 6-digit hexcode prefixed by `#` or one of the keywords defined in the spec.

The spurious `</span>` tag is a syntax error but normally ignored by browsers. However, if there was a preceding `<span>` tag that hasn’t had a matching end tag yet, then (as part of common error recovery) the end tag ends its effect.

So it’s a miracle that the code works anywhere. It does that only because you are using it in a special environment where `font` markup is interpreted in a manner that happens to coincide with your expectations.

Provided that by `4px` you don’t mean 4 pixels but HTML size 4 in a scale from 1 to 7, the size next larger than the default, then the following would be conforming:

```
<font size="4" face="Helvetica Neue" style="color:#313131;">Text hereABC</font>
```

though most people would regard the use of CSS as more appropriate. In CSS, you can use e.g. color values like `rgb(49,49,49)`.

Comment: @yibuyiqu, yes, or at least rgb(...) is defined only in CSS specifications, not in HTML specifications. So if any browser recognizes it in HTML `color` attribute, it’s a browser-specific extension.

Answer (score 0):

use this `<font size="4px" face="HelveticaNeue" style="color:#313131;">Text here</span>ABC</font>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. it works well. it even works with replacing "rgb(49,49,49)" with "313131". I am wondering what was wrong with the original code?

Comment: what is the doctype you are using

Answer (score 0):

The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead!

If you still want to use `color` attribute, you should try Hexadecimal values `#xxxxxx` instead of `rgb(x,x,x)`